# How can an array value be SIX chars long and echoing nothing (string(6) " ")?

Tags: php, arrays

This is really weird. Look what is on my screen right now :

```
$albumGenre : array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Noise"
  [1]=>
  string(6) " "
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Blues"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Blues"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "Blues"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "Blues"
}
```

This is just the output of :

```
var_dump($albumGenre);
```

Can you see where it says [1]=>  string(**6**) " " ??? How can it be that an array value is SIX chars long, but is only seen as " " ?

I know what this value is. It's an "Unknown" mp3 tag. Fine, it's unknow, I just want to get rid of it then. But I can't test for it, if PHP can't reliably tell me what the hell this array value really IS to HIM, see ?

I guess my question really is : How can I really know what's inside an array ? Is'nt var_dump($array) the correct way to know *everything* about $array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that value is a HTML entities `&nbsp`, like

```
var_dump('&nbsp;');
```

Make sure you view source, and copy the output from `var_dump`...

Comment: Bien vu, ajreal ! That's exacly what my value is ; My damaged brain did'nt do the extra mile of thinking..! Thank you everybody !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are 6 Whitespaces.
Repeating whitespaces will collapse to only one whitespace when displayed inside a browser-window.(except you use a `<pre>`-element)

Comment: Then there would be 6 whitespaces visible - this looks like `text/plain` output

Comment: ok, thank you for your answers, I guess you are all right, this value contains something weird. I don't want to deal with it, just get rid of it, so what would be the safest way to do it ? Pekka, how can I test for those "zero lenth" chars ?

Answer (score 1):

Not all characters are printable. Some display as spaces, and some don't display at all - i.e. the text position is not even moved. This can also depend on the "encoding" of the text, and whether the program is using the same encoding as the file's creator intended.

Answer (score 1):

var_dump can only print the printable characters it sees. If you *really* want to know what's in the variable, it might be an idea to install something like [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/).

As a low-fi technique, you could of course attempt to print the individual characters, although this might go awry if the string is in unicode, etc.

Comment: You could output a hex representation of every byte in the string, that would work for Unicode strings as well. This would indeed be nice to have as a feature in `var_dump()`

Comment: @Pekka - Good plan. Could get messy on the (manual) decoding front if it's not UTF-8/16, but it's a sound start.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a number of "zero length" characters, like ASCII control characters or one of the Unicode "zero length" spaces.